# Mission maneuver to Enceladus, I have some results from JPL trajectory browser, what comes next?

Tags: trajectory, astrodynamics, future-missions, enceladus, hohmann

I am working on a project titled 'Astrodynamic mission maneuver to Enceladus'. I have found the launch date using NASA trajectory Browser. Can you let me know how to proceed further?

Comment: Please add more detail! Can you show the date and other results from the trajectory browser, and mention why you think you’re not done? What do you feel is missing? The more you add, the more helpful the answers are likely to be. *Thanks!*

Comment: If it's [the trajectory browser I'm thinking of](https://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/), it's an [Ames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ames_Research_Center) product, not JPL